# How can I make one function for 8 separate classifiers?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, model

I want to calculate the f1 score of the label "negative" for 8 different models. My code for the first 3 models and the dataframe with the results is below. **How can I create a function that I don't need to write separate code for every model?**

```py
# Train model with vectorizer and classifier
# Model training
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Independent_var = reviews_english['tokenized']
Dependent_var = reviews_english['sentiment']

IV_train, IV_test, DV_train, DV_test = train_test_split(Independent_var, Dependent_var, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 500 )

print('IV_train :', len(IV_train))
print('IV_test :', len(IV_test))
print('DV_train :', len(DV_train))
print('DV_test :', len(DV_test))

#Calculate f1 score for all 8 models

#RandomForestClassifier

model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec),('classifier', RandomForestClassifier)])

# Model learning
model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)

# Model prediction on training and test data
pred_train= model.predict(IV_train)
pred_test = model.predict(IV_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
f1_rand = f1_score(DV_test, pred_test, pos_label='negative', average='binary')

#Multinominal NB

model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec),('classifier', MultinominalNB)])

# Model learning
model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)

# Model prediction on training and test data
pred_train = model.predict(IV_train)
pred_test = model.predict(IV_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
f1_multi = f1_score(DV_test, pred_test, pos_label='negative', average='binary')

#BernoulliNB

model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec),('classifier', BernoulliNB)])

# Model learning
model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)

# Model prediction on training and test data
pred_train = model.predict(IV_train)
pred_test = model.predict(IV_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
f1_bern = f1_score(DV_test, pred_test,pos_label='negative', average='binary')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IFF** your code is **identical** for all the models, you could just iterate over each of them. You've already created a list of classifiers `clf_list` so just pass each of those into a function that does all the common steps. Note that if you have some steps which are unique for per model, you'll need to create different functions for them (usually) or add `if...else` blocks where needed.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

RandomForestClassifier = RandomForestClassifier()
MultinominalNB = MultinomialNB()
...  # the lines above
KNeighborsClassifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

clf_list = [RandomForestClassifier, MultinominalNB, BernoulliNB,
            XGBClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, LogisticRegression,
            LinearSVC, KNeighborsClassifier]
# only the names, for your dataframe, order must match:
clf_names = ['RandomForestClassifier', 
             'MultinominalNB',
             ...  # add the rest
             'KneighborsClassifier']

def do_something_with_classifier(clf):
    tvec = TfidfVectorizer()
    model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec),('classifier', clf)])
    # Model learning
    model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)  # where are these variables from?
    # Model prediction on training and test data
    pred_train = model.predict(IV_train)
    pred_test = model.predict(IV_test)
    return f1_score(DV_test, pred_test, pos_label='negative', average='binary')

data = []
for clf in clf_list:
    data.append(do_something_with_classifier(clf))
# or the above as a list comprehension:
data = [do_something_with_classifier(clf) for clf in clf_list]

model_comparison = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['model', 'f1 score "negative"'])
```

Btw, instead of creating variables which point to instances of each classifier just so that you can add them to the list, you could instead directly create the list from those, and skip creating individual variables for each. Or better yet, since you need "text" labels for each to use in your dataframe, create a dictionary where the key is your label/text and the value is the result from the common function:

```py
classifiers = {
    'RandomForestClassifier': RandomForestClassifier(),
    'MultinomialNB': MultinomialNB(),
    'BernoulliNB': BernoulliNB(),
    ...  # add the rest here
    'KNeighborsClassifier': KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5),
}

data = [[name, do_something_with_classifier(clf)] for name, clf in classifiers.items()]
model_comparison = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['model', 'f1 score "negative"'])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! :) However one typeError: "fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" occures in this line "data = [[name, do_something_with_classifier(clf)] for name, clf in classifiers.items()]". Do you see the error? I add the new code to my question.

Comment: @Nicole You're welcome. But don't edit your question like that because now it looks totally out of context wrt the answer. The `.fit` line I used was the same as the one you have above. If it's different for one of the models, then you can't use the same function for all the classifiers.

Comment: And when you get an error message, it will show all the lines of code that led up to it. Add some print statements to see which model gives the error. (Use the longer version of the `for` loop instead of the list comprehension, to add other lines/debug problems.)